# Logical block number to address (Linux filesystem)

Tags: linux, filesystems

```
int block_count;
struct stat statBuf;
int block;
int fd = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);
fstat(fd, &statBuf);

block_count = (statBuf.st_size + statBuf.st_blksize - 1) / statBuf.st_blksize;

int i,add;
for(i = 0; i < block_count; i++) {
    block = i;
    if (ioctl(fd, FIBMAP, &block)) {
                        perror("FIBMAP ioctl failed");
    }
    printf("%3d %10d\n", i, block);
    add = block;
}
char buffer[255];
int fd2 = open("/dev/sda1", O_RDONLY);
lseek(fd2, add, SEEK_SET);
read(fd2, buffer, 20);
printf("%s%s\n","ss ",buffer);
```

Output:

0    5038060

1    5038061

2    5038062

3    5038063

4    5038064

5    5038065

ss

I am using the above code to get the logical block number of a file. Lets suppose I want to read the contents of the last block number, How would I do that?
Is there a way to get the address of a block from logical block number?

PS: I am using linux and filesystem is ext4

Answer (score 0):

The above code actually is getting you the **physical** block number.   The FIBMAP ioctl takes as input the logical block number, and returns the physical block number.   You can then multiply that by the blocksize (which is 4k for most ext4 file systems, but you can get that by using the BLKBSZGET ioctl) to get the byte offset if you want to read that disk block using lseek and read.

Note that the more modern interface that people tend to use today is the FIEMAP interface.  This doesn't require root, and returns the physical byte offset, plus a lot more data.   For more information, please see:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/fiemap.txt

Or you can look at the source code for the filefrag command, which is part of e2fsprogs:

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/misc/filefrag.c

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  In the above case lets consider the physical block number 5038065. For me to read this block I must do a read  lseek(fd2, 5038065 * 4096,SEEK_SET); and  read(fd2, buffer, 20);. Correct me if I am wrong. I did try that before but ended up getting nothing