# How to get Logical Block Address(LBA) using FUSE file system?

Tags: linux, fuse

I need to find the logical block address of files from a fuse based file system. Is there any function available that can find the logical block address of a file within a fuse filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, getting logical block info is done with the `fiemap` ioctl. See non fuse question about it:
[Logical block number to address (Linux filesystem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832934/logical-block-number-to-address-linux-filesystem)

A fuse filesystem can process this ioctl, as any other ioctl, using the libfuse ioctl file operation, if you choose to implement it. See libfuse ioctl example:
https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/example_2ioctl_8c.html

I found that there was an initiative to add a specialized fuse interface to give fiemap like info, but it seems to be incomplete:
https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/issues/72